# Page reloads while navigating in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-design

I'm trying to create a React web app, I have a navbar.
It was working fine actually. But it reloads every time when navigating.
I don't want the page reloads when we navigate with the navbar.

This is my navbar.

```
<MDBNavbarNav fullWidth={false} className="mb-2 mb-lg-0">
  <MDBNavbarLink active aria-current="page" href="/" className="pe-5">
    Home
  </MDBNavbarLink>
  <MDBNavbarLink active href="/#" className="pe-5">
    Features
  </MDBNavbarLink>
  <MDBNavbarLink active href="#" className="pe-3">
    Contact Us
  </MDBNavbarLink>
</MDBNavbarNav>
```

And my router is

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
      <Route path="/features" element={<Features />}></Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />}></Route>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</div>
```

What do I have to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using some links that are usually used for external navigation I guess.
For internal navigation, you should use the `Link` component, from `react-router`:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link
It should look like this:

```
<Link to={`/features`}>Features</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
import Link from 'react-router-dom'
```

use Link instead of 'href'. check React-router-domv6 Link